# Can we defy [convention]?

Tags: support, status-declined, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

Currently, the [convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convention) tag has about 174 questions, 28 of which have been closed.

It's used for the following types of questions:

- Best practices
- Gradle's build-by-convention

Should we burn it?

Comment: Yep. Sounds like a nice future fire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

To quote the wiki:

> A convention is a set of agreed, stipulated, or generally accepted norms. It typically helps common efficiency or understanding but is not required, as opposed to a strict standard or protocol. In programming, a typical kind of convention is the coding convention which stipulates how programmers should format and style their programs.
>
> Here are some examples of conventions that affect programming:
>
> - Coding style: how the source code is formatted (indentation & spacing, location of braces, ordering of methods/functions, etc.). This helps programmers to read and understand the code more quickly, find bugs more easily.
> - File naming: some programs expect the files they process to be named a certain way. For example, the `ant` command assumes by default that the build file is names `build.xml`, which allow developers to omit the file name  in the command line.
> - File structure: programmers are often used to particular way to organize the files, that depends on the language / technology. This allows to read / browse through an unknown code base more easily. Even compilers of some language may expect files to be organized by default in a conventional way. For example, `maven` expects source files to be in a `src` directory and binary files in a `target` directory.
> - Variable naming: some variables with given semantics are conventionally named. For example, `for` loop variable are usually named `i`, `j`, `k`, etc.; and Cartesian coordinates are usually named `x`, `y` and `z`.

This tag indicates the author's desire to know the conventional way to accomplish the task. There are often many ways, but this person is looking for the usual way.

Of course, users who do not understand the scope of SO may post off-topic or overly broad questions, with this tag. But there is nothing wrong or incorrect about the tag itself. (And removing the tag will very likely not prevent any off-topic posts that would have used it.)

---

If I *were* going to do anything with this tag (and I'm not sure I would), it would be to merge it with [idiomatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idiomatic).

Comment: Please clarify how the on-topic [tag:idiomatic] and [tag:convention] questions differ in your view.

Comment: @Deduplicator, I wasn't sure at the time, but now I am. `convention` and `idiomatic` should be merged. The OP doesn't suggest that possibility, but I do.