# Too many [conventions]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

We have both [convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convention) and [conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conventions).

[convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convention) x327:

> A convention is a set of agreed, stipulated, or generally accepted
>   norms. It typically helps common efficiency or understanding but is
>   not required, as opposed to a strict standard or protocol. In
>   programming, a typical kind of convention is the coding convention
>   which stipulates how programmers should format and style their
>   programs.

[conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conventions) x801:

> A generic tag covering any accepted method of doing things, which
>   could include naming, spacing, coding, commenting, etc.

There are the more-specific *-convention tags:

- [naming-conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naming-conventions) x3124
- [code-conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-conventions) x56
- [coding-convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-convention) -> [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style)
- [comment-conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comment-conventions) x7
- [casing-conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/casing-conventions) x6

IMO:

- [conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conventions) should be synonymized or merged with [convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convention) (because the latter has a more descriptive wiki).
- [casing-conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/casing-conventions) should be replaced with or synonymized with [naming-conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naming-conventions).
- [code-conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-conventions) should be synonimzed with [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style) like [coding-convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-convention) was (or removed altogether).

Comment: IMO [tag:convention] and [tag:conventions] are both meta-tags. Don't synonimize them, burninate them.

Comment: @S.L.Barth that was suggested and argued against earlier: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250935/2072269

Comment: I see. That was 3 years ago, however. If we were to discuss it today, the response might be different. I've visited the question and cast my votes.